# python OSM xml overpass

Tags: python, xml, openstreetmap

Reading the data from overpass-API, I have no problem getting the basic fields. From the below example, the lat and lon are easily read. What I cannot manage is the read the various tags with K=xxxx, v=yyyyy ; I need to read the one with k="name" so as to build a list of city name, lat, lon.

The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.

```
<node id="31024030" lat="51.0763933" lon="4.7224848">
  <tag k="is_in" v="Antwerpen, Belgium, Europe"/>
  <tag k="is_in:continent" v="Europe"/>
  <tag k="is_in:country" v="Belgium"/>
  <tag k="is_in:province" v="Antwerp"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Heist-op-den-Berg"/>
  <tag k="openGeoDB:auto_update" v="population"/>
  <tag k="openGeoDB:is_in" v="Heist-op-den-Berg,Heist-op-den-Berg,Mechelen,Mechelen,Antwerpen,Antwerpen,Vlaanderen,Vlaanderen,Belgique,Belgique,Europe"/>
```

Code that I have as yet:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('target.osm')
root = tree.getroot()
allnodes=root.findall('node')
for node in allnodes:
 lat=node.get('lat')
 lon=node.get('lon')
 cityname='' # set default in case proper tag not found
 for tag in node.getiterator():
    print tag.attrib
    # add code here to get the cityname
 print lat,lon,cityname
```

Comment: Forget to include the opening lines of my python code (but very unsure about how to properly format it, something's wrong with typing <cr>):        import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('target.osm')
root = tree.getroot()

Comment: Thanks to the admins who joined this into the original question - one does get pampered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all children of each node and search for a element with a `k="name"` attribute:

```py
for tag in node.findall('tag'):
    if tag.attrib['k'] == 'name':
        cityname = tag.attrib['v']
```

Or by using your `get()` approach:

```
for tag in node.findall('tag'):
    if tag.get('k') == 'name':
        cityname = tag.get('v')
```

Note that a node with a name doesn't necessarily represent a city in OSM. Instead, a city will have additional tags like [place=*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:place).

Comment: The first method works like a charm - everything I was looking after. Seems "saying thanks" is politically incorrect here, so I just owe you one... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider to make use of a existing [OP-API wrapper](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper).

If you don't, you would like to use the [SAX XML](http://www.knowthytools.com/2010/03/sax-parsing-with-python.html) interface for performance. So you will create a parser class and register for callbacks of XML subelements.